# White screen after BASE URL change in PHP?

Tags: php

We had a script in our site that included a

```
_BASEURL_
```

however we needed to change it to https (secure) so we changed the code to:

```
https://www.domain.com/
```

However we now get white screen. Below is the code if anyone can help.

```
    public function getSlideshow() {
    $id_shop = (int)Context::getContext()->shop->id;
    $id_lang = (int)$this->context->language->id;
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'pos_sequence` ps 
        LEFT JOIN `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'pos_sequence_lang`  psl ON ps.id_pos_sequence = psl.id_pos_sequence   
        LEFT JOIN `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'pos_sequence_shop`  s ON ps.id_pos_sequence = s.id_pos_sequence   
        WHERE s.`id_shop` ='.$id_shop.'  
        AND psl.`id_lang` ='.$id_lang.' 
        AND ps.`active` =1
        ORDER BY `porder` ASC';
    $slides = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS($sql);

    if(is_array($slides)){
        $limit = 0;
        $arraySlides = array();
        foreach($slides  as $key => $slideArray) {
             //echo "<pre>"; print_r($slideArray); 
            $newSlide = array();
             foreach($slideArray as $k => $v) {

                if($k=='bgimage' ){
                       $v = https://www.domain.com/.'modules/possequence/images/bgimage_'.$slideArray['id_pos_sequence'].'.jpg';
                 }
                 if($k=='image' ){
                       $v = https://www.domain.com/.'modules/possequence/images/image_'.$slideArray['id_pos_sequence'].'.jpg';
                 }
                 if($k=='image2' ){
                       $v = https://www.domain.com/.'modules/possequence/images/image2_'.$slideArray['id_pos_sequence'].'.jpg';
                 }

                 $newSlide[$k] = $v;
             }
             $arraySlides[$key] = $newSlide;
        }

    }
    return $arraySlides;
}
```

The parts we changed are "bgimage" - "image" and "image2".

Comment: You missed the opening single quotes on `$v =` lines...

Comment: Sorry we arent programmers by any means, could you show how to fix? Thanks very much for your help really appreciate it

Comment: A white screen generally means that an error has happened that will be being logged somewhere, normally in your web server's error log. It'd be helpful if you could find that and post the error—it might even make it immediately obvious to you where the problem is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP-Code is invalid and thus the parser stops with an error. Since your server is set up to not display errors in the frontend (which is good) you just get a white page. You should be able to find the error message in your web server's logs.

Enclose the three occurences of https://www.domain.com/ with single quotes like so:

```
$v = 'https://www.domain.com/'.'modules/possequence/images/bgimage_'.$slideArray['id_pos_sequence'].'.jpg';
```

Or simply put that part into the already existing string:

```
$v = 'https://www.domain.com/modules/possequence/images/bgimage_'.$slideArray['id_pos_sequence'].'.jpg';
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the opening quotes on some of your lines...

```
if($k=='bgimage') {
    $v = 'https://www.domain.com/modules/possequence/images/bgimage_'.$slideArray['id_pos_sequence'].'.jpg';
}
if($k=='image') {
    $v = 'https://www.domain.com/modules/possequence/images/image_'.$slideArray['id_pos_sequence'].'.jpg';
}
if($k=='image2') {
    $v = 'https://www.domain.com/modules/possequence/images/image2_'.$slideArray['id_pos_sequence'].'.jpg';
}
```

Edit: After reading your question again, it's probably likely that you can actually just update the `_BASEURL_` constant somewhere in the code. Save yourself the headache and just search for where that is set (it will look something like this):

```
define('_BASEURL_', 'http://domain.com');
```

If you update it there, it will save you having to find all of the pleaces where it needs changing in your code.